# How to upload a BufferedImage using Jetty HTTP client and MultiPartContentProvider?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, javax.imageio, jetty-9

With Jetty 9.4.21.v20190926 I run a custom servlet (a WAR-file), which is able to generate images like this one:

[image: generated image]

by the following code:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpReq, HttpServletResponse httpResp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    // ...drawing code skipped here...
    g.dispose();
    httpResp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    httpResp.setContentType("image/png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", httpResp.getOutputStream());
}
```

This works well and now I would like to add another feature to my servlet: [uploading the same image by HTTP POST to another website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads/) (I would trigger the upload by calling an URL on my servlet by a hourly cronjob).

I understand, that I should use [MultiPartContentProvider](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/MultiPartContentProvider.html) and the following code:

```
MultiPartContentProvider multiPart = new MultiPartContentProvider();
multiPart.addFilePart("attached_media", "img.png", new PathContentProvider(Paths.get("/tmp/img.png")), null);
multiPart.close();
```

however I would prefer not to save the generated image as a temporary file.

Instead I would like to use [BytesContentProvider](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/BytesContentProvider.html) or maybe [InputStreamContentProvider](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/ByteBufferContentProvider.html)… but how to *marry* them with `ImageIO.write()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use a `OutputStreamContentProvider` instead of a `PathContentProvider` in your `multipart.addFilePart()`?

See https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/OutputStreamContentProvider.html

Then you can just use the `ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStreamContentProvider);`

Example:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = ...;

 // the output for the image data
 OutputStreamContentProvider content = new OutputStreamContentProvider();
 MultiPartContentProvider multiPart = new MultiPartContentProvider();
 multiPart.addFilePart("attached_media", "img.png", content, null);
 multiPart.close();
 // Use try-with-resources to autoclose the output stream
 try (OutputStream output = content.getOutputStream())
 {
     httpClient.newRequest("localhost", 8080)
             .content(multipart)
             .send(new Response.CompleteListener()
             {
                 @Override
                 public void onComplete(Result result)
                 {
                     // Your logic here
                 }
             });

     // At a later time...
     ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
 }
```